# Angular can't find service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I'm building Angular 1.6.6 app with Django Rest Framework following [tutorial by TrackMaven](http://engineroom.trackmaven.com/blog/getting-started-drf-angularjs-part-5/).

My app can't find any services:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: retail

Here is my service file:

```
retail
.factory('Chain', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(
        'http://localhost:8000/chains/:id/',
        {},
        {
            'query': {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }
        },
        {
            stripTrailingSlashes: false
        }
    )
});
```

And my app.js:

```
'use strict';

var retail = angular.module("retail", []);

angular
    .module('SampleApplication', [
        'appRoutes',
        'retail',
        'ngResource',
    ]);
```

I think it's all about scopes but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Are both scripts loaded on the same file ?

Comment: Post the code where you load the scripts. Also, are they declared inside IIEF?